# How can i store a line by line user input as an integer list in Haskell?

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, input, mergesort

i am extremely new to haskell, and i was tasked with creating a program that merge sorts n number of integers. The program asks for how many elements that it is going to be sorting, and the elements to be sorted would be inputted line by line. I haven't even gotten to sorting it yet, but i am having trouble with storing the line by line input in a list. This is what i have so far.

```
storedelems = []

inputelems 0 = return storedelems
inputelems n = 
 do
    storedelems <- getLine 
    inputelems (n-1)


main = (inputelems 4)
```

When i finish entering the line by line numbers i want to sort, it just returns []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `inputelems 4` you just read to `storedelems` one line and just forget it, and after all unmemorable reads you just return global `storedelems` which you defined as `[]`.

For you there is function `replicateM`. For using it you firstly must import module `Control.Monad`:

```hs
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
```

Now you can use it so:

```hs
main = replicateM 4 getLine
```

So, now `main` reads 4 lines and create list of read strings.

If you want list of integers, you can modify `main` so:

```hs
main :: IO [Int]
main = replicateM 4 (read <$> getLine)
```

But you have to realise that it is wrong if your function will be named `main` because `main` is special function which must has type `IO ()`.

You also can modify your solution so:

```hs
inputelems 0 = return []
inputelems n = 
 do
    storedelem <- getLine 
    (storedelem : ) <$> inputelems (n-1)
```

Now your `storedelem` won't be forgotten.

Comment: Thank you! For the last solution, i inputted 1,2,3,4, and it inputted ["1","2","3","4"], are they chars or integers?

Comment: @vasics It's strings

Comment: `readLn` behaves better than `read <$> getLine`: if the parse fails, with `readLn` you get an IO exception right away (and so easily catchable in a predictable way), while with `read <$> getLine` you get a pure exception and it is delayed until that list element is evaluated.